# delete route not found in express after ajax delete method call

Tags: node.js, express, routes

```
app.delete('/block/:name', function(request, response){
    console.log("name");
//    delete blocks[request.blockName];
//    response.sendStatus(200);
});
```

all other routes except delete route are working.
need help

Comment: could you please add more details about exactly what is not working?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
app.delete('/block/:name', function(request, response){
    console.log(req.params.name);
//    delete blocks[request.blockName];
//    response.sendStatus(200);
});
```

`req.params.name` references the `:name` in your app, whereas `"name"` just outputs the word **name**.